# visual studio 2013 issue with less and the file it creates

Tags: visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, less, web-essentials

I'm using **visual studio 2013** and have web essentials for update 4 (2.5.4) installed.

I'm running the web application from visual studio (I happen to be using Chrome) and bootstrap v 3.3.4.

I've removed any reference to bootstraps css file.  I have my own less file that imports the bootstrap.less file

```
@import "../js/BootStrap.3.3.4/less/bootstrap.less";
```

when I hit F5, it says that my less file compiled to Test1.css.

In my master page I have a reference to the Test1.css file.  So it looks something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="/js/js1.11.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/BootStrap.3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="CSS/Test1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

However, when the page renders it looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="/js/js1.11.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/BootStrap.3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="/js/BootStrap.3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and it works. Where does the boostrap.min.css come from and why is it working and not using what I have in my masterpage. Further more, the bootstrap.min.css, I've looked using a `dir *.css /s` command and can not find that file anywhere.

Your ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry for the post.  It's working now.  Visual studio had an error that made it shutdown and when I restarted it, things work more as I would have thought they would .  It's now using the correct css file.

Comment: Well ...just delete this post then.